# Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to refactor my js code to be more dry-conventioned, but stuck this error. Here is my code

```
function validate_field(e){
    console.log(typeof e);
    $(e).focusout(function(e){
        var price = $(e).val();
        var number = parseInt(price, 10);
        console.log(number)
        if (number < 0)
        {
            $(e).val(0);
        }
    })
}
$(function(){
    validate_field('#price');
})
```

According to stacktrace error is somewhere here `var price = $(e).val();`
What am i missing here?

Comment: What type of element do you expect e to be?  Will it always be a form component such as input/select?

Comment: string, and it is string according to `console.log(typeof e);`

Comment: e - What element is this....? have you tried like $(this).val()...?

Comment: So a String with a jquery selector? Something like `#someId`

Comment: yes, exactly. I pass this string as argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
   function validate_field(e){
        console.log(typeof e);
        $(e).focusout(function(ev){
-------------------------------^ here you are redeclaring the e previously passed as selector 
            var price = $(e).val();
            var number = parseInt(price, 10);
            console.log(number)
            if (number < 0)
            {
                $(e).val(0);
            }
        })
    }
    $(function(){
        validate_field('#price');
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

You are interfering the `e` argument with `e` variable of function. It should be :

```
function validate_field(s) { // here also ? I have set "s" as parameter, you can set any word you like
    console.log(typeof s); // noticed the difference here?
    $(s).focusout(function(e) { // noticed the difference here?
        var price = $(this).val();
        var number = parseInt(price, 10);
        console.log(number)
        if (number < 0)
        {
            $(e).val(0);
        }
    });
}
```

You can also change your event argument for minor change as @dakait did.

Answer (score 0):

Reassigning the variable is causing problem.

```
function validate_field(field){ // both variable should not be same e & 'e' of inside function
    console.log(typeof e);
    $(field).focusout(function(e){
        var price = $(field).val();
        var number = parseInt(price, 10);
        console.log(number)
        if (number < 0)
        {
            $(field).val(0);
        }
    })
}
$(function(){
    validate_field('#price');
})
```

**or**

can use the below code directly without calling other function in script

```
$(function(){
    $('#price').focusout(function(e){
            var price = $(this).val();
            var number = parseInt(price, 10);
            console.log(number)
            if (number < 0)
            {
                $(this).val(0);
            }
        })
});
```